# Javascript date object with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Bit of a newb to stackoverflow and spending way too much time thinking about this, but in a nutshell I'm trying to figure out the best approach and least amount of code for this to happen.  I've got a conditional that will perform an action based on the time of day. See below:

```
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getHours();

if(time < 12){
header.prepend('Morning ');
link.attr('href', 'css/morning.css');
} else if (time >= 12 && time <= 18){
header.text('its afternoon time');
link.attr('href', 'css/day.css');
} else {
header.prepend('Night ');
link.attr('href', 'css/night.css');
}
```

I've also got a similar action happening with a click event:

```
$('button').click(function(){
var styleswitcher = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
link.attr('href', 'css/' + styleswitcher + '.css');
});
```

Is there a way to combine them into one function, I feel like I'm repeating myself by calling the stylesheet twice in the conditional and on the click event.  So something along the lines of if the time and the click event match show the proper stylesheet.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just package up the code and put it into the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function change_css() {    
        var date = new Date();
        var time = date.getHours();
        var styleSwitcher = 'night';

        if(time < 12) {
            styleSwitcher = 'morning';
        }

        else if(time >= 12 && time <= 18) {
            styleSwitcher = 'day';
        }

        link.attr('href', 'css/' + styleSwitcher + '.css');
    }

    change_css(); // First call on initial run.

    $('button').click(function() {
        change_css();
    });

});
```

Note: I haven't had time to test this code, but the idea is correct.

Comment: Thanks! This works but is there a way to have it so on document load it runs the time conditional without having to click the button? So it runs the conditional on load but if you click a button it can load the style sheet based on the button click as well.

Comment: See the edited code. It may be beneficial to study up on Javascript, however.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I was really over thinking this one.